# facebook share image size issue

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, share

I am struggling with a facebook image size problem,

while Iam sharing the images on FB its took only small sizes(thumbnails). even i share a high resolution image (1600x1200 or 900x400) all sizes its resizing.

sharing with following codes.

```
<a class="btn" target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=sample title&amp;p[summary]=custom summary&amp;p[url]=domainname&amp;p[images][0]=http://hidefwalls.com/wp-content/g/high-resolution/high-resolution-14-xooacj0rr2-1600x1200.jpg">share on facebook</a>
```

So my question is is there any way to share a large image size (at least 400x209).
I followed many [links](http://www.jonloomer.com/2013/09/11/facebook-link-thumbnail-image-dimensions/) but non of the help me.

Also Please let me know any option to restrict an image that shows in share options.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sharing/posting through the following code. Hope it helps. fbImg && fbTxt  are dynamic images pulled from my site through jquery

```
function publishWallPost() {
      var fbImg = $('.head .headerLeft p img')[0].src;
      var fbTxt = $('.head .headRight span.artistName').text();
      FB.ui({
          method: 'feed',
          name: 'Pandora - Which Star Are You',
          caption: 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Pandora/119285608270259?id=119285608270259&sk=app_535647489852225',
          description: 'According to Pandora\'s Which Star Are You competition, I\'m ' + fbTxt + '. Click on the artist\'s picture to find out which star you are!',
          link: 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/Pandora/119285608270259?id=119285608270259&sk=app_535647489852225',
          picture: fbImg
        },
        function (response) {
          console.log('publishStory response: ', response);
        });
      return false;
}


window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
      FB.init({
        appId: '535647489852225',
        status: true,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true
      });
};

(function () {
      var e = document.createElement('script');
      e.async = true;
      e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
      document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Comment: is this share large image or it resize image. required an APP right ?

Comment: This is to post on facebook wall/ share on facebook wall. It uses js facebook api. Let me see if I can dig out the documentation for you. But it works. You can check out the app here https://www.facebook.com/pages/Pandora/119285608270259?id=119285608270259&sk=app_535647489852225 Also, you will notice that on the last page, I have the post to wall that pulls out the image and shows it

Comment: I read somewhere that the sharer method is deprecated and no longer supported. As far as I can tell, the best replacement for sharing a page of your site is the Feed Dialog. Link: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.ui/

Comment: thanks for your answer, the sharer method not yet depreciated.Feed dialog uses open graph protocols so it will not work for me i have a page with dynamically changing product images,description etc(ajax)

Comment: aha good lucks. Good to know that the sharer method not yet depreciated. I ended up using the js method thinking it is. Otherwise it is easier through the sharer method

Comment: The old version of the Share dialog __is__ deprecated. The [Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) does not take additional parameters other than the URL to share any more, but instead takes the info (title, description, thumbnail) from the Open Graph meta tags of the URL being shared.